# Google Chrome Task Manager update rate: How to slow it down?

Tags: google-chrome

Is there any way to slow down the sample/update rate of Chrome's Task Manager?

The display works fine for e.g. sorting tasks by memory footprint, because that's pretty stable; but it's terrible for finding the top few CPU-burning tasks, presumably because the CPU usage is rather bursty and the default ~1 second sample rate catches tasks at random levels of activity, so they jump around wildly and are hard see or click on.  Lengthening the sample time to 5 or 10 seconds should give a much more stable and accurate average of what tasks are really using the most CPU.

Comment: I would add, network bandwidth usage jumps around similarly, making the Chrome Task Manager of very limited use for monitoring that per-tab either

Comment: Try sorting by **CPU Time**, as a sometimes-works-workaround. (If CPU Time doesn't already show, right click to add it.)    
This issue is already 15? years old – it's going to be 2045 and we'll all be living in OASIS before Google improves this.